# I had my application started after removing all the vulnerabilities and updating all the dependencies and I am seeing a below error

Tags: spring-boot, maven, postman

"timestamp": "2022-01-01T20:43:46.241+00:00",
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error", "message":"io.netty.util.internal.ObjectUtil.checkNonEmpty(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;"

I am sending a response in the postman in the JSON format and getting a below error.
How can I get the correct response?

Comment: The error you provide is very generic. You should provide the full error stacktrace and a [mre] to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.